# Spring security: In 3.1, bypass security filter for only 'GET' requests

Tags: spring-security

I want my service to perform authentication only for incoming POST/PUT/DELETE requests and bypass it for any GET requests. Spring versions less than 3.1,  had the ‘filters=”none”’ attribute which could be used to bypass all security filters for a specific URL pattern. In 3.1, ‘filters=”none”’ was deprecated and the alternate solution was to use ‘security=”none”’ attribute for "http" element. This does not support configuration based on type of request coming in (GET/PUT/POST/DELETE).

I am using Spring 3.1.1 and the current config is as below:

```
<!-- Just un-comment any resource if you don't want authentication to be done on them -->
<http pattern="/base/version" security="none"/>

<!-- Secure resources -->
<http create-session='stateless' entry-point-ref="tokenAuthenticationEntryPoint">
  <custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="tokenAuthenticationFilter" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/v1/abc/**" method="GET" filters="none"/>  //This doesn’t work currently
  <intercept-url pattern="/v1/abc/**" method="POST" access="ROLE_USER"/>
  <intercept-url pattern="/v1/abc/**" method="PUT" access="ROLE_USER"/>
  <intercept-url pattern="/v1/abc/**" method="DELETE" access="ROLE_USER"/>
  <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
</http>
```

How can I bypass the security filters for pattern="/v1/abc/**" method="GET" in Spring 3.1?

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to get around the problem - Using Expression-Based Access Control, I used access="permitAll" which configures authorization without disabling filters.

```
<!-- Just un-comment any resource if you don't want authentication to be done on them -->
<http pattern="/base/version" security="none"/>

<!-- Secure resources -->
<http create-session='stateless' entry-point-ref="tokenAuthenticationEntryPoint" use-    expressions="true">
  <custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="tokenAuthenticationFilter" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/v1/abc/**" method="GET" access="permitAll"/>
  <intercept-url pattern="/v1/abc/**" method="POST" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
  <intercept-url pattern="/v1/abc/**" method="PUT" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
  <intercept-url pattern="/v1/abc/**" method="DELETE" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
  <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
</http>
```