# In Spring Security, how to bypass the GET method of an URL; but not the POST one

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-security

How can I configure, so that the GET version of an URL is bypassed by the custom filters, but not the POST version of that URL. I tries using "filters=none" in , but its not working. My configuration is like:

```
<http auto-config='true' use-expressions="true" create-session="never" >
    <custom-filter position="FIRST" ref="authenticationFilter" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/v0_2/app" method="GET" access="permitALL" filters="none"/> // Its not working
    <intercept-url pattern="/v0_2/app" method="POST" access="permitALL" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitALL" />
</http>
```

Even with ""secuirty=none" option, there is no provision of providing the http method. It bypasses all http methods of the URL.

```
<http pattern="/v0_2/app" security="none" />
```

Please let me know, how can I do bypass the GET method only.

-Thanks

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21072581/spring-security-in-3-1-bypass-security-filter-for-only-get-requests

Answer (score 0):

You can have something like :

```
<intercept-url pattern="/v0_2/app" method="GET" access="permitAll"/> 
    <intercept-url pattern="/v0_2/app" method="POST" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
```

or

```
<intercept-url pattern="/v0_2/app" method="GET" access="permitAll"/> 
        <intercept-url pattern="/v0_2/app" method="POST" access="denyAll"/>
```

denyAll will make every POST request to go through filter.